# MySQL Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use'

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, mysql-connector

Actually, I am using Spring boot and there is an error in creating the table in the database. I am using MySQL as my database

the error are

**Error Showing in Spring Boot**

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'like bigint not null, time_created time, primary key (blog_id)) engine=InnoDB' at line 1
```

**Error when I try to manually create the table**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'like bigint not null, time_created time, primary key (blog_id)) engine=InnoDB' at line 1
```

**My command**

```
create table blogs (blog_id integer not null, date_created date, discription varchar(999), dislike bigint not null, like bigint not null, time_created time, primary key (blog_id)) engine=InnoDB;
```

**And my Entity**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int blogId;

@Column(length = 999)
private String discription;

@CreatedDate
private LocalDate dateCreated;

private LocalTime timeCreated;
private long like;
private long dislike;


public blogs(int blogId, String discription, LocalDate dateCreated, LocalTime timeCreated, long like,
        long dislike) {
    this.blogId = blogId;
    this.discription = discription;
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    this.timeCreated = timeCreated;
    this.like = like;
    this.dislike = dislike;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error lies in your SQL Statement. `LIKE` is a keyword/reserved word and cannot be used as a name of an attribute.

Change your SQL Statement of the `blogs` table creation to the following one:

```
CREATE TABLE blogs (
    blog_id        integer        not null, 
    date_created   date, 
    discription    varchar(999), 
    dislike        bigint         not null, 
    liked          bigint         not null, 
    time_created   time, 
    primary key (blog_id)
) engine=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem with **read**. Instead of changing the attribute name, I've surrounded **read**  with two backticks (`).

Change

```
private long like;
```

to

```
@Column(name = "`like`")
private long like;
```

Comment: I agree to this encapsulation but it is not a good practise to use Reserved Words as it would to lead First to a Confusion at later stage or when someone else reads or takes over the maintenace, and second there might be errors being thrown every time one forgets to encapsulate the keyword.